# Trying to make my bash client automatically go to specific folder

Tags: bash, git-bash, hyper

I want to be able to open the embedded terminal in vscode and have it automatically go to the correct directory. But also, if I open git bash just by itself, I want it to automatically go to D:\Coding , is this possible?

I tried setting up a bashrc file which solves my second problem, but now when I open the terminal in vs code it goes to my coding folder instead of the correct directory.

Comment: Can you determine programmatically when you are in VScode? Does it set some environment variable?

Comment: I mean I could but I was hoping maybe to do somethings with the like open in function of a shortcut, is that possible?